# How can I show hidden class in div tag default?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="inst17" class="block_activity_modules  block list_block hidden" role="navigation" data-block="activity_modules" data-instanceid="17" aria-labelledby="instance-17-header" data-dockable="1">
<div class="header" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_292">
<div class="title" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_234">
<div class="block_action" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_291">
  <img class="block-hider-hide" tabindex="0" alt="Hide Activities block" title="Hide Activities block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=core&amp;rev=-1&amp;image=t/switch_minus" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_290">
  <img class="block-hider-show" tabindex="0" alt="Show Activities block" title="Show Activities block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=core&amp;rev=-1&amp;image=t/switch_plus"><input type="image" class="moveto customcommand requiresjs" alt="Move this to the dock" title="Dock Activities block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=core&amp;rev=-1&amp;image=t/block_to_dock">
</div>
<h2 id="instance-17-header">Activities</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content"> 
<ul class="unlist">
  <li class="r0">
    <div class="column c1">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/mod/forum/index.php?id=1">
        <img src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=forum&amp;image=icon" class="icon" alt="">
         Forums</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see a class add in div name hidden. It comes on click a button but i want default hidden class come.

Comment: go into to your text editor search in the html page for this div, point the mouse before the last " of the class atribute and than press space and type hidden, press ctr+s to save the page

Comment: hidden class comes  on click a button in jquery

Comment: remove the click event add the class `hidden` in the class atribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add the `hidden` class to your element on load:

```js
$(function(){
 $('#inst17').addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden{
 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inst17" class="block_activity_modules  block list_block" role="navigation" data-block="activity_modules" data-instanceid="17" aria-labelledby="instance-17-header" data-dockable="1">

<div class="header" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_292">
<div class="title" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_234">
<div class="block_action" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_291">
  <img class="block-hider-hide" tabindex="0" alt="Hide Activities block" title="Hide Activities block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=core&amp;rev=-1&amp;image=t/switch_minus" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1429685975009_290">
  <img class="block-hider-show" tabindex="0" alt="Show Activities block" title="Show Activities block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=core&amp;rev=-1&amp;image=t/switch_plus"><input type="image" class="moveto customcommand requiresjs" alt="Move this to the dock" title="Dock Activities block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=core&amp;rev=-1&amp;image=t/block_to_dock">
</div>
<h2 id="instance-17-header">Activities</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content"> 
<ul class="unlist">
  <li class="r0">
    <div class="column c1">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/mod/forum/index.php?id=1">
        <img src="http://192.168.1.112/mth/moodle27/theme/image.php?theme=unapvirtual&amp;component=forum&amp;image=icon" class="icon" alt="">
         Forums</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```